# Configuring mbsync with AuthMech XOAUTH2

Tags: ubuntu, email, plugin, sasl

I can't seem to figure out how to get `mbsync` to work with OAuth for Gmail because I can't get `mbsync` to find the xoauth2 `sasl` plugin on Ubuntu.
I'm fairly confident that everything about my `mbsync` config for OAuth is working correctly (e.g. manually testing the PassCmd successfully generates an access token)

edit: I have installed `sasl-bin` via apt, and https://github.com/robn/sasl2-oauth from source.

---

**Questions**

- How can I manually "register" a `sasl` plugin for `mbsync`? (aka add it to the list of 'available' SASL mechanisms in the first log pasted below)
- Could this issue be due to another component in my "email stack"? Some threads I've read suggest recompiling mutt from source, but I don't understand why mutt would be causing auth problems.

---

Using `mbsync` installed via `nix-env`, I haven't been able to get past

```
C: 0/1  B: 0/0  M: +0/0 *0/0 #0/0  S: +0/0 *0/0 #0/0
IMAP error: selected SASL mechanism(s) not available;
   selected: XOAUTH2
   available: GS2-IAKERB GS2-KRB5 SCRAM-SHA-1 SCRAM-SHA-256 GSS-SPNEGO GSSAPI DIGEST-MD5 EXTERNAL OTP CRAM-MD5 PLAIN LOGIN ANONYMOUS
C: 1/1  B: 0/0  M: +0/0 *0/0 #0/0  S: +0/0 *0/0 #0/0
```

I've also tried reinstalling `mbsync/isync` from apt, as well as building `isync` from the source. Both of which result in the following error.

```
Notice: Master/Slave are deprecated; use Far/Near instead.
C: 0/1  B: 0/0  F: +0/0 *0/0 #0/0  N: +0/0 *0/0 #0/0
Error: SASL(-1): generic failure: Unable to find a callback: 32775
C: 1/1  B: 0/0  F: +0/0 *0/0 #0/0  N: +0/0 *0/0 #0/0
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to your previous hints. I've managed to get XOAUTH2 working in SASL and use it with mbsync. Here is how I got it working on my Ubuntu 20.10:

### Install Cyrus SASL OAuth2

```bsh
# Clone the Cyrus SASL OAuth2 sources.
git clone https://github.com/moriyoshi/cyrus-sasl-xoauth2.git

# Configure and make.
cd cyrus-sasl-xoauth2
./autogen.sh
./configure

# SASL2 libraries on Ubuntu are in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/; modify the Makefile accordingly
sed -i 's%pkglibdir = ${CYRUS_SASL_PREFIX}/lib/sasl2%pkglibdir = ${CYRUS_SASL_PREFIX}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sasl2%' Makefile

make
sudo make install

# Verify XOAUTH2 is known to SASL.
saslpluginviewer | grep XOAUTH2
```

### mbsync

Older versions (up to 1.3.1?) have PassCmd buffer set to 80 -- and this is not enough for OAuth2 tokens. I compiled the current 1.4.0:

```bsh
# Clone the isync/mbsync 1.4 sources.
git clone --branch 1.4 --depth 1 https://git.code.sf.net/p/isync/isync isync-isync

# Configure and make.
cd isync-isync
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
```

### mutt_oauth2.py

Download mutt_oauth2.py from https://gitlab.com/muttmua/mutt/-/blob/master/contrib/mutt_oauth2.py and make it executable.

I have a modified version that creates a socket with OAuth2 tokens. So I can then access the tokens via the socket:

```bsh
curl --unix-socket ~/.mutt/oauth2.socket x
```

Please note that your mileage may vary and you will need a different PassCmd to access the OAuth2 tokens.

### mbsyncrc

Configure mbsync to use XOAUTH2 and set PassCmd to execute the above curl command:

```
IMAPAccount <account-name>
Host outlook.office365.com
User <first.last@yourcompany.com>
AuthMechs XOAUTH2
PassCmd "curl --unix-socket ~/.mutt/oauth2.socket x"
SSLType IMAPS
SSLVersions TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2
```

mbsync then works as expected; notice the output from curl below:

```
$ mbsync -a
C: 0/1  B: 0/0  F: +0/0 *0/0 #0/0  N: +0/0 *0/0 #0/0  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  1963    0  1963    0     0   479k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  479k
C: 1/1  B: 15/15  F: +0/0 *0/0 #0/0  N: +847/847 *0/0 #0/0
```

Comment: Hi! I used something similar on Unix in the past, but can't get cyrus-sasl-xoauth2 to work on Mac OS. Do you know how that might work?

Comment: Thanks for this step-by-step. Could you elaborate on why the `socket with OAuth2 tokens` useful? Also, can you link to your modified version?

Comment: For me, using the original script `mutt_oauth2.py` directly in the `PassCmd` worked, after setting up a token as explained in the [mutt_oauth2.py README](https://gitlab.com/muttmua/mutt/-/blob/master/contrib/mutt_oauth2.py.README): `PassCmd="path/to/mutt2_oauth2.py path/to/token"`. But I also had to install `libsasl2-modules-kdexoauth2` as mentioned in @Rovanion's answer, as well as [sasl-xoauth2](https://github.com/tarickb/sasl-xoauth2) and set up the `/etc/sasl-xoauth2.conf` config file

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 22.10 installing `libsasl2-modules-kdexoauth2` solved the "IMAP error: selected SASL mechanism(s) not available;" issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on figuring out the same issue. Here are some resources that may help.

1. https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=238727
2. https://isync-devel.narkive.com/i6h4k9hB/mbsync-xoauth2-and-gmail
3. http://blog.onodera.asia/2020/06/how-to-use-google-g-suite-oauth2-with.html

I haven't succeeded in fixing the error but it seems you need to have https://www.cyrusimap.org/sasl/ installed. Next, use one of these plugins:

- https://github.com/sweetums/SASL-OAuth
- https://github.com/robn/sasl2-oauth

Hope that helps. I'll keep trying to see if I can get all this to work.

Comment: Thanks, yea seems like we're in a similar place. But the threads I've found where someone fixes this issue are always arch related fixes.

Comment: Have you tried installing this? https://github.com/moriyoshi/cyrus-sasl-xoauth2.That seems promising but having some issues that are OSX issues.

Comment: yea I think I had before, and just re-compiled but mbsync still doesn't see it as an available `SASL` mechanism. After building there is output about from the install about how to link with the library. But not sure what I need to rebuild with this lib linked